# WM_GETTEXT not retrieving text from Window

Tags: c++, sendmessage

I have set a hook and using the `CBTProc` function to monitor window activity, then called a `SendMessage` with `WM_GETTEXT` to get the window text.

```
 LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc (int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::ofstream out("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\temp.txt", std::ios::app);
    CBTACTIVATESTRUCT *act = (CBTACTIVATESTRUCT *) lParam;

     HWND hWnd = (HWND) wParam;
     TCHAR wnd_title[1000];
    if(nCode == HCBT_ACTIVATE)
    {
         SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, sizeof(wnd_title), LPARAM(wnd_title));
         out << "Processor: " << wnd_title << "\n";

    }
    out.close();
    return CallNextHookEx(hhkCBT, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

However it doesnt print out the text from processes such as Notepad, Microsoft Word.

I'm trying to retrieve the window title of the active/focused window and print it out. Any hints on how to do this?

I tried GetWindowText, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Hooking 64-bit processes requires you to create a 64-bit DLL that can be injected into such processes.  With a 64-bit process to activate it.  That makes SetWindowsHookEx() rather painful to use these days, you'd better have a look-see at the much easier to use SetWinEventHook().

Comment: @HansPassant The DLL I create is 32-bit, are you saying that if its injected into a process that is 64-bit its not going to work? But my low level keyboard and mouse hook seem to be working fine.

Comment: I'm saying that it *can't* work, a 64-bit process cannot use a 32-bit DLL.  A 64-bit DLL is a rock-hard requirement.  So right now you'll only ever see anything from 32-bit processes.  Low-level hooks are very different, they don't require a DLL to be injected.  Instead Windows calls your hook callback directly.  Same way with SetWinEventHook().

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the explaination, I reliased now that the DLL I create is 32-bit (I'm using a 64bit machine); I should have tested to see if it was actually being injected. As for your suggestion on the SetWinEventHook() I found an article that I found helpful http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/25/10404940.aspx